# Pass parameters to rails emails template using Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I am using Mandrill to send some batch emails.

I have the following code:

```
m = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
    message = {
    :subject=> @template.subject,
    :from_name=> @template.branch.name,
    :from_email=>"myemail@example.com",
    :to=>mails,
    vars: {
            'MESSAGE' => @template.message,
          },
    :html=>render_to_string('dashboard_mailer/send_campaign', :layout => false),
    :preserve_recipients => false,

    }
    sending = m.messages.send message
```

I know I can print the MESSAGE variable by adding `*|MESSAGE|*` inside my `dashboard_mailer/send_campaign.html.erb` file. But I would also like to display some dynamic content. For example display `@items.name`, where items have different size.

Its actually more complicated than just displaying a set of names (I could create a string in the controller and display it with a variable). What I need to display involves some html tags, which is why it could be nice to be able to loop through the variable inside the `send_campaign.html.erb` file

Is it possible to pass a variable to the rails template?

Thanks